# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target doesn't work, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: regex, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have backend and fronted applications. I have tried to create one ingress for fronted where   both paths will be matched (*host.com/api/v1/reference/list/test1* and *host.com/api/v1/reference/test2*). The second one works fine, but the first give me error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().** Here is my ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2$3
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - host.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: host.com
      http:
        paths:       
          - backend:
              serviceName: service-backend
              servicePort: 80
            path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```

service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

Does anyone know why my URLs are not getting rewritten and the requests are not delivered to the backend service for host.com/api/v1/reference/test2 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

resolved - bug inside application